# Flutter how to create horizontal scrollable cardview using list of data

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a horizontal scrollable cardviews. Inside the cardview, I want to set the image and textview.The data inside cardview will be fetch from the list.Now how to set the list data inside the cardview

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
         debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
         home: new Scaffold(
             body: new SingleChildScrollView(
                 child: Column( 
                     mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,    
                     children: <Widget>[   
                         buildBody(),
                         productsCard()   
                         ],
                     ),
                 ),
             )
         );
     }
    Widget buildBody() {
        return Stack(
            // alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            children: <Widget> [
                new Image(
                    image: new AssetImage('assets/homebg.png'),
                    ), 

               Positioned(
                   left: 50.0,
                   right: 50.0,
                   bottom: 40.0, 
                   height: 64.0,// adjust this if you want some padding
                   child: RaisedGradientButton(
                       onPressed: () {
                           Navigator.push(
                               context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StylistPage()));
                        },
                        child: new Text("BOOK AN APPOINTMENT", 
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),

                         ),
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: <Color>[const Color(0xFF000000),const Color(0xFF000000), const Color(0xFF40079B)],
                        ),
                    ), // child widget
                ),
               ]
            );
    }

    Widget productsCard(){
        return Container(
            child: ListView(     
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, // <-- Like so
                children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        width: 160.0,
                        color: Colors.red,
                     ),

                     Container(
                         width: 160.0,
                         color: Colors.blue,
                      ),

                     Container(
                         width: 160.0,
                         color: Colors.green,
                      ),

                  ],
            )
        );
    }
```

// Here is my list of data.I have four values in each item of the list.

```
 List<ProductsCollection> productData = []
 ..add(ProductsCollection('Discipline curl','https://sgdfgdgd/jdkjdhj.png/jashdghd',20,'akhsgdahghsgdh'))
 ..add(ProductsCollection('Discipline curl','https://sgdfgdgd/jdkjdhj.png/jashdghd',20,'akhsgdahghsgdh'))
 ..add(ProductsCollection('Discipline curl','https://sgdfgdgd/jdkjdhj.png/jashdghd',20,'akhsgdahghsgdh'));
```

When I try to call the productsCard method, I'm not able to see any widgets in my screen.The screen appears blank after the code and also the number of cars should depends upon the number of values available in the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your list isn't showing because you haven't given any height to it. Add `height` to the Container wrapping the ListView.

To create a dynamic list you can use `ListView.builder` and to show your data inside a card, `Column` will help you. `itemCount` will build productData.length number of cards.

```
    Widget productsCard(){
    return Container(
      height: 200.0,
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: productData.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) =>
              Card(
                child: Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('Discipline curl'),
                      Text('https://sgdfgdgd/jdkjdhj.png/jashdghd'),
                      Text('20'),
                      Text('akhsgdahghsgdh')
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
        )
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: After giving height also cards are not visible

Comment: Cards aren't showing because you haven't used Cards and haven't put data in cards. I've updated the answer according to your description.